# sql statement to return results where there is no match

Tags: mysql, sql

I had 2 tables: fruits and vegetables
fruits is as follow:

```
id - name       - weight
0    apple        2
1    banana       4
2    strawberry   7
3    oranges      5
```

vegetables is as follow: id, name,color,weight,vitamins are fields/columns

```
id - name     - color - weight - vitamins
0    tomato             1     
1    pumpkin            5  
2    eggplant           4
```

I want to return the results where the weight is not the same on the left table (fruits)
in this case it would be : apple, strawberry
what would be the best method please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select * from Fruits where weight not in (Select weight from vegetables)

Answer (score 4):

Deepesh's solution is perfect, but here is a solution using left join:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bb74/2

```
SELECT fruit.*
FROM      fruit
LEFT JOIN vegetable ON vegetable.weight = fruit.weight
WHERE vegetable.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
       SELECT * FROM Fruits WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM  vegetables WHERE  vegetables.weight = fruits.weight)
```